# Converting SDE.ST_Intersects to sdo_geometry_?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, geospatial

I am using the below query to return the data where the shape column is of ST_GEOMETRY type

```
SELECT ZONE_C 
FROM ZONING a 
WHERE SDE.ST_Intersects (a.shape, SDE.ST_Point('1167518.17076043', '1850605.40829976', 2)) = 1
```

We have another table where the shape column is of datatype SDO_GEOMETRY, can you please let me know how to rewrite the query above for sdo_geometry.

Thanks

Comment: There is no Oracle version 9.3. And why are you migrating to a deprecated version?

Comment: sorry i was using arcgis 9.3 with oracle, now we are migrating to arcgis 10.2 with oracle